# How do I populate my UITableView with data from JSON array?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have been trying to populate my tableView for the pas 4 days and I keep hitting dead ends.

I have been through the questions on here and tried some of the suggestions that others have been given, but none of them seem to work. Basically I have JSON data sent from my website and that is populating an array that I then wish to put into a tableView.

The NSLog is returning all correct info, but seems to stop once the array is created, and doesn't have any data logging after the array populates.

here is my .h file

```
//
//  reportsTestViewController.h
//  TESG-iConnect
//
//  Created by TESG on 7/03/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TESG. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface reportsTestViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *reportsTable;

    NSString *response;
    NSMutableArray *reportsArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *response;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *myDataIvar;



@end
```

and my .m file

```
//
//  reportsTestViewController.m
//  TESG-iConnect
//
//  Created by TESG on 7/03/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TESG. All rights reserved.
//

#import "reportsTestViewController.h"
#import "ReportsDataObject.h"

@interface reportsTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation reportsTestViewController

@synthesize response;

@synthesize myDataIvar;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
//    

    //Create your request pointing to the test page
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tesg.com.au/allCustBuild.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    //initialize it when you create your connection
    if (connection){
        self.myDataIvar = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
        [self.myDataIvar setLength:0];
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
        [self.myDataIvar appendData:data];
        [reportsTable reloadData];
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed: %@", error.userInfo);
    }

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    //this is where you would parse the data received back from the server
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.myDataIvar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Received Data: %@",responseString);
    [self setupReportsFromJSONArray:self.myDataIvar];

}

-(void)connectionWasASuccess:(NSData *)data{
    [self setupReportsFromJSONArray:data];
}



-(void)setupReportsFromJSONArray:(NSData*)dataFromReportsArray{
    NSError *error;
   // NSMutableArray *reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arrayFromServer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromReportsArray options:0 error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"error parsing the json data from server with error description - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary *eachReport in arrayFromServer)
        {
            ReportsDataObject *report = [[ReportsDataObject alloc] initWithJSONData:eachReport];
            [reportsArray addObject:report];
        }
        NSLog(@"Array Populated");
        NSLog(@"%u reports found",reportsArray.count);
        //Now you have your reportsArray filled up with all your data objects
    }
}


-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //We check against table to make sure we are displaying the right number of cells
    // for the appropriate table. This is so that things will work even if one day you
    //decide that you want to have two tables instead of one.
//    if(tableView == reportsTable)
    {
        return([reportsArray count]);
    }
    return 0;
    NSLog(@"%u",reportsArray.count);
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reportsTableIdentifier = @"ReportsTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reportsTableIdentifier];
    if(cell)
    {
        //set your configuration of your cell
    }
    //The beauty of this is that you have all your data in one object and grab WHATEVER you like
    //This way in the future you can add another field without doing much.

    if([reportsArray count] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"no reports to show";
    }
    else{
        ReportsDataObject *currentReport = [reportsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [currentReport reportName];
        // in the future you can grab whatever data you need like this
        //[currentReport buildingName], or [currentReport reportName];
    }
    return(cell);
}

@end
```

and my NSLog output

> 2014-03-11 14:40:13.006 TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] PostData:
>   username=&password= 2014-03-11 14:40:13.119
>   TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] Response code: 200 2014-03-11 14:40:13.119
>   TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] Response ==> {"success":1} 2014-03-11
>   14:40:13.120 TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] Success: 1 2014-03-11
>   14:40:13.120 TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] Login SUCCESS 2014-03-11
>   14:40:14.677 TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] Received Data:
>   [{"id":"7684","title":"POT Feb 2011","date":"2011-04-18
>   10:49:27","link":"1303087767_POT 113 Lonsdale St
>   feb11.pdf"},{"id":"7683","title":"Audit Feb 2011","date":"2011-04-18
>   10:49:12","link":"1303087751_CA 113 Lonsdale St feb
>   11.pdf"},{"id":"11189","title":"AESMR 2011","date":"2012-01-30 09:49:28","link":"1327877368_AESMR 113 Lonsdale Street, Melbourne
>   2011.pdf"},{"id":"8761","title":"Annual 2011","date":"2011-08-02 12:55:56","link":"1312253756_Annual Passive 113 Lonsdale St May
>   2011.pdf"},{"id":"8762","title":"Audit May 2011","date":"2011-08-02 12:56:16","link":"1312253775_CA 113 Lonsdale Street May
>   11.pdf"},{"id":"8763","title":"POT May 2011","date":"2011-08-02 12:56:34","link":"1312253794_POT 113 Lonsdale Street May
>   2011.pdf"},{"id":"10286","title":"Audit Aug 2011","date":"2011-11-08 14:31:34","link":"1320723094_CA 113 Lonsdale Street Aug 
>   11.pdf"},{"id":"10287","title":"POT Aug 2011","date":"2011-11-08 14:31:46","link":"1320723106_POT 113 Lonsdale Street Aug 2011.pdf"}]
>   2014-03-11 14:40:14.678 TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] Array Populated
>   2014-03-11 14:40:14.678 TESG-iConnect[29384:a0b] 8 reports found

I cannot seem to find where the code is not working. can someone point me in the right direction please??

EDIT TO INCLUDE dataObject JUST IN CASE

```
//
//  ReportsDataObject.h
//  TESG-iConnect
//
//  Created by TESG on 7/03/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TESG. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReportsDataObject : NSObject

-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;

@property (assign) NSInteger reportId;
@property (strong) NSString *buildingName;
@property (strong) NSString *reportName;
@property (strong) NSString *reportDate;
@property (strong) NSString *reportLink;

@end
```

---

```
//
//  ReportsDataObject.m
//  TESG-iConnect
//
//  Created by TESG on 7/03/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TESG. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ReportsDataObject.h"

@implementation ReportsDataObject

@synthesize reportId;
@synthesize buildingName;
@synthesize reportName;
@synthesize reportDate;
@synthesize reportLink;

-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        //NSLog(@"initWithJSONData method called");
        self.reportId = [[data objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        self.buildingName =  [data objectForKey:@"buildingname"];
        self.reportName = [data objectForKey:@"reportname"];
        self.reportDate = [data objectForKey:@"reportdate"];
        self.reportLink = [data objectForKey:@"reportlink"];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Try to reload the table at the end of `connectionDidFinishLoading`, then put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: FYI, you put an `NSLog` after `return`, which is useless, because it is never reached.

Comment: are you getting response from server

Comment: How do i enter a break point?

Comment: I added the reloadTable after connectionDidFinishLoading and added the breakpoint and got this error:

2014-03-11 15:50:27.961 TESG-iConnect[30583:a0b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:6246
2014-03-11 15:50:27.963 TESG-iConnect[30583:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: where is reportName in your Array? that is displayed in NSLog

Comment: if([reportsArray count] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"no reports to show";
    } is it working or not? does tableview displays this output no reports to show when your array count is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised your uitableviewcell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {


        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, there seemed to be no difference in the output either

Comment: initialise cell and reload tableview when you have array

Comment: comment this line return 0; in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Still the same result Surender

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call reloadData at the end of the setupReportsFromJSONArray method rather than in didReceiveResponse since you don't create the reportsArray until then.

Comment: this just received error 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: @Djinné22, depending on how you made your cell, you might also need to include the if(! cell) clause that Surrender Rathore has in his answer.

Comment: @Djinné22, did you set your controller as the data source for your table view?

Comment: yes, I set the datasource and delegate for the UITableView as my viewController

Comment: You should move the log in numberOrRowsInSection to before the return statement, and see if it gets called, and if so, what it's returning.

Comment: it returns 2014-03-11 16:18:52.157 TESG-iConnect[31247:a0b] 8

Comment: @Djinné22, have you checked to make sure that you have the same identifier for your cell in IB, and the one you have in cellForRowAtIndexPath (ReportsTableCell)?

Comment: explain what that means please. I don't have an IBOutlet for my cell, only my tableView. Am I supposed to have one for the actual cell as well?

Comment: @Djinné22, where did you make the cell? Do you have a table view in a storyboard? You don't need an IBOutlet, but you need to set the identifier for the cell in IB (storyboard or xib) to match the one you have in code.

Comment: I started with a viewController and added a tableView. I have tried it both with a cell in storyboard and I gave it the same identifier, I also tried it without a cell in story board based on a tutorial I watched but that didn't help either. I just added the cell back to the storyboard and assigned the identifier (Cell) based on the help I received from Surender but it is still not populating

Comment: @Djinné22, if the cell has the identifier "Cell" in the storyboard, then you need to have:  static NSString *reportsTableIdentifier = @"Cell"; in your code. The two MUST match.

Comment: @Djinné22, not according to your posted code (which still shows ReportsTableCell) , and the comment you just posted which says you changed it to "Cell". You need to update your question with the code that you are actually using now, and what errors, if any, that you're getting. You've tried so many things, I can't tell what code you're running now.

Comment: It looks like I may have found the issue. The ReportsDataObject was accessing data that wasn't there because of the field names I had put in. I changed them to match and it seems that the data is coming up ok now……..mostly! I really appreciate your help rdelmar

Comment: @Djinné22, that doesn't explain the 'NSInternalInconsistencyException error that you were getting. I guess you must have changed something else that fixed that.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, yes I think that was fixed by the if (!cell) fixed that one. Once again I appreciate how much time you spent in this with me